# Double-quote inside Json inside CSV: do I need to escape the backslash?

Tags: json, csv, gson

I have a CSV file that contains a JSON string, which itself has a double-quote in one of its values.  This means that the double quote must be escaped twice, first with another double-quote, and then with a backslash.  However, I was not able to get this to work until I had escaped the backslash as well!  Otherwise, I got a JSON parse error.

In other words, this raw value: `"` should became this in JSON: `\"` but then this did not work in the CSV file (JSON Parse Error): `\""` but THIS did: `\\""`

*Or, for a clearer example:*

Value with double quote:  `You "know" it!`

JSON: `[{ "value" : "You \"know\" it!" }]`

CSV (JSON Parse Error): `"John Smith","[{ ""value"" : ""You \""know\"" it!"" }]"`

CSV (DID work): `"John Smith","[{ ""value"" : ""You \\""know\\"" it!"" }]"`

This seems a bit unexpected.  It's as if I have to escape a backslash in JSON.  Why would I need to do this?

If it makes any difference, I'm using Java to parse all this, with OpenCSV for parsing the CSV data and Gson for parsing the JSON data.

Comment: The parser does not work, because the right way is `"John Smith","[{ ""value"" : ""You \""know\"" it!"" }]"`

Comment: @aborruso The only difference I can see is that you removed the space after the comma after "John Smith".  I have also removed that space but the behavior remains the same.

Comment: James, in my opinion it's your CSV parser that does not work properly, because this is a properly formatted CSV row `"John Smith","[{ ""value"" : ""You \""know\"" it!"" }]"`. See points 2.7 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#section-2

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's old question, but still, I needed to do something similar. My solution was to save csv in db, and then export it to json format.